# Why is android studio not showing virtual android emulator for my flutter code, whereas its showing for java android code?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, avd-manager

Im trying to write a code in flutter on android studio but unable to run virtual android device on android studio for flutter code

Comment: any screenshots? logs? anything? didnt you try flutter doctor

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to run the code or the device?

have you created a new VD from AVD manager?!

it will be helpful to add more details of photos so we can help you better